# Serializing a List<> exported as an ICollection<> to XML

Tags: c#, xml, c#-3.0, xml-serialization

I have a C# .NET 3.5 application where I would like to serialize a class containing a `List<>` to XML. My class looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot("Foo")]
class Foo
{
    private List<Bar> bar_ = new List<Bar>();

    private string something_ = "My String";

    [XmlElement("Something")]
    public string Something { get { return something_; } }

    [XmlElement("Bar")]
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars
    {
        get { return bar_; }
    }
}
```

If I populate it like this:

```
Bar b1 = new Bar();
// populate b1 with interesting data
Bar b2 = new Bar();
// populate b2 with interesting data

Foo f = new Foo();
f.Bars.Add(b1);
f.Bars.Add(b2);
```

And then serialize it like this:

```
using (System.IO.TextWriter textWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\foo.xml"))
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, f);
}
```

I get a file that looks like this:

```
<Foo>
    <Something>My String</Something>
</Foo>
```

But, what I want is XML that looks like this:

```
<Foo>
    <Something>My String</Something>
    <Bar>
        <!-- Data from first Bar -->
    </Bar>
    <Bar>
        <!-- Data from second Bar -->
    </Bar>
</Foo>
```

What do I need to do to get the `List<>` to appear in the XML?

Comment: I don't believe you can `XmlSerialize` an interface. Why do you want to serialize as `ICollection` anyway? Serialize as `List<T>` and return to the consumer an `ICollection<T>` ...???

Comment: @IAbstract - I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean to mark the `private List<Bar> bar_` with the `[XmlElement("Bar")]` tag? That does not change the output. Also, the `XmlSerializer` documentation suggests that it does work with both `IEnumerable` and `ICollection` interfaces. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: I think IAbstract has it - you can't serialize an interface. So instead you should change Foo so that Bars is a List, not an ICollection

Comment: It seems wrong to return a concrete List<> from an accessor. Even FX-COP will complain. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Oh. It's a known issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/528310/xmlserializer-fails-to-deserialize-readonly-members-that-are-collections-if-they-have-a-private-setter

Comment: Use my interface driven serialization: http://xmlserialization.codeplex.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` requires that serializable properties have a setter. Besides that, the `XmlSerializer` can not serialize interface properties. The following code will work:

```
[XmlElement("Bar")]
public List<Bar> Bars
{
    get { return bar_; }
    set { throw new NotSupportedException("This property 'Bars' cannot be set. This property is readonly."); }
}
```

If you don't like this solution (the exception is kinda ugly) then you could implement `IXmlSerializable` and write your own custom serialization.

**Edit:** Artur Mustafin is right, members that implement `IEnumerable` or `ICollection` *don't need a setter*, as is explained on [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The XmlSerializer gives special treatment to classes that implement `IEnumerable` or `ICollection`. A class that implements `IEnumerable` must implement a public `Add` method that takes a single parameter. The Add method's parameter must be of the same type as is returned from the `Current` property on the value returned from `GetEnumerator`, or one of that type's bases. A class that implements `ICollection` (such as CollectionBase) in addition to `IEnumerable` must have a public `Item` indexed property (indexer in C#) that takes an integer, and it must have a public `Count` property of type integer. The parameter to the `Add` method must be the same type as is returned from the `Item` property, or one of that type's bases. For classes that implement `ICollection`, values to be serialized are retrieved from the indexed `Item` property, not by calling `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: This is wrong and ugly answer, this is wrong because it works event without setter, see my post

Comment: The XmlSerializer DO NOT requires that serializable properties have a setter

Answer (score 4):

Giving a correct answer, there is no point to create ugly setter to the `List<T>` public property, to throw an exception.

This is because `List<>` is already implements `ICollection<T>` and provides method with signature void `Add(T object)` which is used by Serialization mechanism;

You are only have to add the setter to the public properties being serialized, and change `ICollection<T>` to `List<T>`:

```
[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    private List<Bar> bar_ = new List<Bar>();

    [XmlElement("Something")]
    public string Something { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Bar")]
    public List<Bar> Bars { get { return bar_; } }
}
```

You will get an output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Something>My String</Something>
  <Bar />
  <Bar />
</Foo>
```

Also, it is a better idea to serialize xml in-memory, to see the results, or test it, as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Bar b1 = new Bar();
     // populate b1 with interesting data
     Bar b2 = new Bar();
     // populate b2 with interesting data

     Foo f = new Foo();
     f.Bars.Add(b1);
     f.Bars.Add(b2);
     f.Something = "My String";

     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     using (System.IO.TextWriter textWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms))
     {
         System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
         serializer.Serialize(textWriter, f);
         string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
         Console.WriteLine(text);
     }

    Console.ReadKey(false);
}
```

To serialize using interfaces, use my project [XmlSerialization](http://xmlserialization.codeplex.org)

Comment: Just to be sure, are you saying it is "a better idea to serialize xml in-memory" all the time in case you would like to see what is going on or were you simply proposing a way for the OP to test more easily? I suppose it is the second option but if it is the first one, could you elaborate please?